Is it ok to work for an event management company?
Salam,
I want to know if its ok to work for an event management company that also deals with providing DJs at wedding ceremonies and sounds etc in USA.I basically take care of cobtracts and all so is it haram?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].
